# NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9843)

Tags: ios, uiwebview

im using a UIWEBView which load URL like example.com which works fine and asks server for new url to load if server provides ip address like 192.168.1.23 then this error occured otherwise URL like  example.com work perfect , i don't understand what's issue

ATS is already disable , and ip and url is using HTTPS

This Function Call when button clicked and Refreshed

```
    - (void)getHTMLData {
reachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
[reachability startNotifier];

NetworkStatus remoteHostStatus = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus];

if(remoteHostStatus == NotReachable)
{

    UIAlertView* alertView;
    alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                           message:@"No Network Reachability " delegate:self
                                 cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [alertView show];

}
else
{
NSString  *phyIdTemp=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]  objectForKey:@"phyId"];

NSString *pathUrl = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"URL"];
NSURL* nsUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:getDetails, pathUrl]];

[self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:nsUrl]];
  NSLog(@"URLWEBVIEW %@",nsUrl);
```

}

Thanks in Advance ..

Comment: Please put some code. Your question is too generic.

Comment: what code UIWEBVIEW ?? or or whole class

Comment: All the code that could be relevant to understand your issue. Making this exercise will perhaps point you to the right direction, and you may find the answer by yourself. Anyway, it will help others to help you ;-)

Comment: @Rafouille Unable to find answer , just using a quick fix , BTW Thanks